# Realm accessed from incorrect thread - dispatch async

Tags: swift, multithreading, realm

I'm trying to do some sorting on a different thread, however i keep getting `Realm accessed from incorrect thread`. Below is what i'm tried so far.

```
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            // do some task
            self.organizationArray = GetOrganization.sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(realm.objects(Organization), location: self.lastLocation!)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.lastLoadedPage = self.lastLoadedPage + 1

                if numberOfResults < self.limit {
                    //Hide FooterView
                    self.moreDataAvailable = false
                    self.hideTableViewFooter()

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: A `Realm accessed from incorrect thread` exception is thrown when one of Realm's objects is accessed from a thread other than that which it was created on. You can add a [breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) in Xcode to determine where in your app this is happening. There's no obvious problem of this nature in the code snippet you've posted so the problem must exist elsewhere in your app, or be in some code that you've elided from the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're calling the shown code snippet from the main thread, e.g. from a view controller as it seems, you're likely using a `RLMRealm` instance from the main thread on another thread.

```
 let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            // Get a Realm for the current thread
            RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];

            // do some task with that instance instead
            self.organizationArray = GetOrganization.sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(realm.objects(Organization), location: self.lastLocation!)
            // …
```